# WPF how to bind Item of ItemsSource in a ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to bind a item in a list view but i dont want to bind a property of the item but the item it self ... So the item source is a list of Device objects and i want to bind the current device object to my customcontroll DependencyProperty. How do i do this ?

```
<ListView x:Name="deviceView" ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <local:DeviceTile DeviceName="{Binding Path=???}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Use `{Binding}`.

Comment: Define the element as `<local:DeviceTile DeviceName="{Binding}"/>` which should bind the current object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 <local:DeviceTile DeviceName="{Binding}"/>
```

OR

```
 <local:DeviceTile DeviceName="{Binding Path=.}"/>
```